# Can SSL certificate(.crt) decompiled from an apk file be a threat?

Tags: android, ssl, ssl-certificate

In order to use https via SSL/TLS, a ssl certificate is required.

I included the certificate files on my /raw directory, and used them on my Retrofit module.

The problem is that the content inside the /raw directory can be accessed via an attacker by simply decompiling the apk file.

In such situation, are there any possible threats using those SSL certificates?

If so, what can I do to prevent such incident?

Comment: No. A certificate is a public document, intended to be circulated. It *is* circulated in the SSL handshake. There is no secret information inside it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understanding the concept of public/private key will help answer this question.

The public key is meant to be distributed to the world, as it does not prove identity. It is used for encrypting data that only the recipient should know (the holder of the private key).
The private key, on the other hand, does prove identity, so it would be very dangerous to spread it. The private key, on the other hand, is used to sign (!) data, and any data signed with it (unless the certificate is revoked or expired) is valid. The holder of the public key can simply verify the validity of the data using the public key.

The .crt file contains a public key (and not a private key, that's what the .key file is for), so there's not really much they can do with it. They can't sign anything with it, which would be the dangerous point.

Comment: In advance, what about a .pem file? Does it make any difference?

Comment: The .crt file is a great deal more than just a public key.

Comment: @March3April4 It depends on what's in the PEM file. If it contains a private key, don't leak it. If it just contains certificates and/or CSRs, it isn't private.

Comment: I meant to simplify by as much as possible the answer. I am aware that it is more than a public key (for example, it contains the signature of the CA). Anyways, corrected a bit my answer. Still, there's no danger adding it.

Comment: You can simplify as much as you like, but when you say 'the .crt file is a public key' you are peddling misinformation; and when you change that to 'it contains a public key' the part following 'so' is no longer a valid inference. For example a key pair, contains a public key, but it isn't safe to distribute it.

Comment: Corrected once again to be more specific on the fact that the .crt file doesn't have a private key, although I think it was quite understandable as I didn't make any references to it.

Comment: Sigh. The point is that *everything* in a .crt file is public. The fact that it contains a public key *among other things* proves exactly nothing. There is nothing 'understandable' about misinformation and invalid inferences.